# read and rewrite lines in file in C++

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I need little help with my homework in C++. My task is to write a function for borowing books form library called `borrow(name,surname, student_id, book_id)`, which will  connect  information of borrowed book's ID and student's informations in the file.

File looks like this:

```
John Jackson 45 0

Michael Gregory 34 56

Ann Cawitch 23 0

Chris Lamb 34 50
```

...

First two words are name and surname of students. First number represents student's ID and second one represents ID of book. If ID of book is 0, it means that student hasn't borrowed book yet, so he can borrow some book. If ID of book is not 0, it means that student can't borrow a book until he returns the old one.
So, when student borrows book, ID of book in file should change from zero to some number

This is my code:

```
void borrow(string name, string surname, int student_id,int book_id )
{

    string a;
    string b;
    int c=0;
    int d;
    fstream f2;
    f2.open("students.txt", ios::out |ios::in);
    while (f2 >> a >> b >> c>> d)
    {
        if (a==name && b==surname && c==student_id)
        {
            if (d==0)
            { 
                f2 <<name<<" "<<surname<<" "<<student_id<<" "<<book_id<<"\n";
                cout<<" Book is borrowed successfully"<<endl;
                f2.close();
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                cout<<" Student can't boorow book because he has already borrowed one."<< endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        else (c==0);
    }
    if (c==0)  cout<<" Student isn't sign up  library."<<endl;  
}
```

Whenever I call function (for example **borrow**(John, Jackson,45,15)), I get answer  "Student isn't sign up  library."

Am I on a right path?
Where did i make  mistakes?

Comment: Have you verified that it is getting the information you expect from the file?  And/or that you initial `if` in the loop is doing what you expect?

Comment: you should use an other variable to check if a student is in the "list", because c will be 0 for each line that does not match the student you were looking for.

Comment: `else (c==0);` ??

Comment: Cannot reproduce ! Your code works fine ... IMHO the problem lies in the access to file "students.txt". You should control you correctly opened your database file.

Comment: No, his code does not work fine as `students.txt` is not updated with the new book id as per the specification. There are still a lot of problems with this code - file i/o is not working, logical errors, poor formatting, etc.

Comment: I strongly suggest using your _debugger_. Trace the program's execution line by line. You'll see where it fails.

Comment: "c==0" means that student does not exist. Can anyone help me with file i/o? I am relativly new with that area.

Comment: I suggest getting a simple program working that can read in a file, modify a line and write it back out. Once you have that working, *then* you can add the book-checking-out-logic. In general, that's how good programmers code - they start off with something small *that works* and then build off of it incrementally.

Comment: @ZvonePeran the line `else (c==0)` is basically a no-op, all it does is return whether `c` is equal to `0` and do nothing with the result.  What is it supposed to do, set `c` to `0`?

Comment: @RPGillespie : The question was related to the fact that program always answered *Student isn't sign up library.*. What I mean is that provided it opens the file "students.txt", it displays as expected * Book is borrowed successfully*. So my conclusion is that OP's current problem is that his program does not correctly opens his file. Of course this program is far from complete ...

Comment: @RPGillespie, I don't have idea how to make that program which will do given task